# Magento: I have a working ‘add to cart’ button on a CMS page…How can I make a ‘custom quantity’ system work?

Tags: php, javascript, magento

I’m working on this page (http://liff2013.com/screenings2) where I have the functionality to add an item to a cart (despite being a CMS page) working through this code:

```
<button onclick="setLocation('http://liff2013.com//checkout/cart/add?product=55&qty;=1')" class="addToCart">Purchase Tickets</button>
```

But I’m trying to figure out how someone can add multiple tickets. The dropdown menu in place now doesn’t actually work, it’s just there to help illustrate how it should work.

Any ideas? I was thinking maybe some javascript or php would be able to accomplish this, but not 100% sure.

Thanks!

Comment: After 'qty' word you have ';' symbol, remove it from there and maybe your example will work.

Comment: Well the add to cart button works, it just adds one ticket. I'd like for it to work where say they selected '2' from the drop down box, it'd change that '1' in the code I have to a 2, and therefore add 2 tickets when clicked.

As it stands now, the select box isn't tied in to the button.

Comment: Something like this: http://jsfiddle.net/pktMJ/

Except it'd edit the HTML of the button code. And also, I wouldn't want to have 60 different ID's (there will be about 60 different films)

Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

Use this code for the onclick attribute:

```
onclick="setLocation('http://liff2013.com//checkout/cart/add?product=55&qty='+jQuery(this).prev().val())"
```

I removed your hard-coded value `qty=1` and wrote `jQuery(this).prev().val()`
This Javascript code simply get the value of the element  just before the button.

If you move the `<select>` or `<button>` element it may not work anymore, so I advise you to use a better selector like an id, for instance: `jQuery('#quantity-dropdown-1').val()`